# Rename Multiple Files in SVN

Tags: powershell, svn

Is there a way to easily rename multiple files, all located in a single folder, in SVN? Preferably using something basic like command line or powershell commands.

For example, if I was just renaming them in windows explorer, I would use a powershell command like `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "Rev A","RevB"}` to change "Rev A" to "Rev B" in all file names. Is there a way to do something similar and have SVN recognize it?

Comment: You might be looking for [`svn mv`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SVNs [move command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) you can rename a file (Which is basically *moving*). A PowerShell script could look like:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    svn mv $_.Name $_.Name.replace("Rev a", "Rev B")
}
```

As @salvolds says, you should choose your filenames carefully. More important, you should use your version control system carefully, but I won't judge for that.

In the end that is a file removal and a new addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you change name to your files, say file-revA to file-revB, directly in file system (as your script suggest), SVN will recognize a deletion for file-revA. Then you will have to add the new file-revB to SVN to let SVN know about it.

Pay attention: file-revB is a completely new file from SVN perspective and as a consequence you will only see his history starting from when it has been added to SVN (you will lose the "link" with the previous file-revA).

To avoid losing the history you can use the specific svn move command.

In any case you should choice your file names carefully at the start of your project or preferably rename them only when really needed or when the history doesn't matter to avoid having troubles when reading your history.

Comment: If the rename is done through the corresponding svn command the history will be preserved